# ActionType in action 'Source' is not available in region 'EU_WEST_3'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create CodePipeline with TF and I'm running into this error

```
Error: creating CodePipeline (Pos-CodePipeline-TF): InvalidActionDeclarationException: ActionType (Category: 'Source', Provider: 'GitHubEnterpriseServer', Owner: 'AWS', Version: '2') in action 'Source' is not available in region 'EU_WEST_3'
```

Here is the tf file

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name     = "Pos-CodePipeline-TF"
  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::920148820790:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-eu-west-3-be-pos-connection"

  artifact_store {
    location = aws_s3_bucket.pos_solvee_codepipeline_bucket.bucket
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "GitHubEnterpriseServer"
      version          = "2"
      output_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact"]
      namespace        = "SourceVariables"

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn        = "my-connection-arn"
        FullRepositoryId     = "my repo"
        BranchName           = "main"
        OutputArtifactFormat = "CODE_ZIP"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      namespace        = "BuildVariables"
      input_artifacts  = ["SourceArtifact"]
      output_artifacts = ["BuildArtifact"]
      version          = "1"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName = "pos-solve-build"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
      name            = "Deploy"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "ElasticBeanstalk"
      namespace       = "DeployVariables"
      input_artifacts = ["BuildArtifact"]
      version         = "1"

      configuration = {
        ApplicationName = "pos-system-docker"
        EnvironmentName = "Pos-system-docker-env"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "pos_solvee_codepipeline_bucket" {
  bucket = "pos-solvee-codepipeline-bucket"
}
```

As I was searching I saw that value for `ConnectionArn` usually is data `terraform_remote_state` but I had this configuration created manually so I already have `ConnectionArn`.

Also tried to have `Github` instead of `GitHubEnterpriseServer` but that was causing an error too.

Let me know if there is anything else I need to share.

Answer (score 0):

Although I havent tested this particular TF, I see an issue in the source action. For GitHub version 2, GitHub and GitHub Enterprise Cloud, use the CodestarSourceConnection action. So,

```
Category: Source
Owner: AWS
Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
Version: 1
```

Also, from the docs, *you must maintain the correct case for the FullRepositoryId value. For example, if your user name is some-user and repo name is My-Repo, the recommended value of FullRepositoryId is some-user/My-Repo*.

Hope this helps.

References :

- [Update a GitHub version 1 source action to a GitHub version 2
  source action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/update-github-action-connections.html)
- [CodeStarSourceConnection for Bitbucket, GitHub, and GitHub
  Enterprise Server actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html)
- [Terraform Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16042)